# Calculate step response from impulse response LTI-system.

Tags: fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Can someone please give me a few pointers on how to calculate the step response for an LTI system with this impulse response?? 
\begin{equation}
h[n] = 2^nu[n].
\end{equation}

Comment: convolution of the impulse response with a step input gives the output aka the step response.

Comment: Thank you yes I know that but I am a little unsure of how to perform the convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step response,$y(n)=h(n)\ast u(n)$ $$\displaystyle y(n)=\sum\limits_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}h(\tau)\;u(n-\tau)$$
$$=\sum\limits_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(2^{\large \tau}u\left(\tau\right)\right)\;u(n-\tau)$$
$$=\sum\limits_{\tau=0}^{\infty}2^{\large \tau}\;u(n-\tau)$$
$$=\sum\limits_{\tau=0}^{n}2^{\large \tau}=1+2+4+\cdots+2^n=\frac{1(1-2^{n+1})}{1-2}=2^{n+1}-1=2(2^n)-1$$

Comment: Since convolution is commutative, one could also have done $ y(n)=\sum\limits_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}h(n-\tau)\;u(\tau) $ and the result would have been the same, albeit a little trickier.